# How do the `aapcs` and `aapcs-linux` ABI options differ when compiling for bare-metal ARM with gcc?

Tags: abi, cortex-m, bare-metal, compiler-options, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I am trying to port an application to ARM's `arm-none-eabi-gcc` toolchain. This application is intended to run on a bare-metal target.

The only two suitable values for the `-mabi` option in this case appear to be `aapcs` and `aapcs-linux`. From [Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmEabiPort) and [Embedded Linux from Source](https://kanj.github.io/elfs/book/armMusl/cross-tools/abi.html) I know that `aapcs-linux` uses a fixed 4-byte enum size, whereas `aapcs` defines enums as "variable length". However, I can't find any information on what other differences (if any) there might be.

Does anyone know the full list of differences between these two ABI options?

Comment: you have a lot of assembly language you have to port?